# how to correct an error on angular Failed to load http://localhost/api/notification/create.php: Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: angular7

When I send the data to PHP, the browser responds with an error:

```
Failed to load http://localhost/api/notification/create.php: Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Here is my code to send the data

Comment: Please post your code and review this guide to help you get the most out of your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with your CORS implementation. Specifically, you seem to be missing the [Http method "options"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).

You can resolve this by either by:

1. Implementing CORS correctly in your PHP code. You should prefer this way if your production setup requires you to have the PHP code running on a different domain
2. or by using the [Angular CLI Proxy](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md). You should prefer this way if you only need the different domains (e.g. localhost:4200 for angular and localhost(:80) for PHP)